# actionlistener not attached to a jbutton?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am trying to create a timer, and from what I can gather it involves using an actionlistener that is not attached to any jbutton, etc. the problem is, I do not understand how to do this. The java documentation on timers says to do:

```
package testing;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class timer{
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //...Perform a task...
       }
 }; //line with the error
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start(); 
}
```

, but whenever I this it says syntax error on :, < expected... could somebody please explain to me what I am doing wrong, and how to fix it? - a java noob

EDIT: the full error message is `Syntax error on token ";", < expected`

Comment: Did you use `javax.swing.Timer` or `java.util.Timer`?

Comment: It is fine to use an ActionListener with a SwingTimer as the Swing Timer API will tell you, so don't be concerned that you're not adding it to a JButton. All you're doing is implementing the observer pattern for the timer, with the observers (the ActionListeners) being notified here when the timer "ticks" rather than when a button is clicked. Please show the *full error message*. Please indicate which line causes the error to occur.

Comment: as far as I can tell, this is javax.swing.timer

Comment: The snippet you give runs fine for me. Post more code, especially the part containing the line the error is on.

Comment: updated the code to show full error message and the full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have code, `new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();`, outside of a constructor or method where it doesn't belong. Currently it's dangling naked in the class, in a location where only variable declarations are allowed. Put that code inside of your constructor. Also rename your class so that it starts with an upper-case letter and so will follow Java naming conventions:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

// rename class to begin with an uppercase letter
public class MyTimer{
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //...Perform a task...
       }
 }; 

 public MyTimer() {
   // the code below is now happily placed inside of your class's constructor.
   new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start(); 
 }

}
```

Comment: so could somebody please explain why putting new timer inside a constructor fixed it?

Comment: @quixotrykd: again, you can only place variable and constant declarations out naked in the class outside of constructors or methods. Method or constructor calls without assigning to a newly declared variable are not allowed outside of a method, constructor, or other similar block (such as one of the initializer blocks).

Comment: sorry one final question, despite the fact that this fixes the error, the timer still does not work... any idea why?

Comment: in order to have the timer run, you have to create an object of type MyTimer, right?

Comment: @quixotrykd: in order to have the Timer run, you must create a MyTimer object, yes, but you'll also need a Swing GUI that is visible to start and maintain the Swing event thread.

Comment: @quixotrykd: for example, I use a Timer for a "game loop" in my code example created today for this question here: [Java last added button allows agent.move, rest dont](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18969962/522444).

Comment: as a java noob, i do not understand anything you just said(sorry). If you had a chance, could you give me an example of a working timer? thanks

Comment: @quixotrykd: I just did. If it is too complex, please feel free to search this site for Swing Timer examples as there are many to be found for you to use, many written by me.